# Chart JS parsing data with xAxisKey

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to create a graph with date and time on the x axis and values on the y axis. This works if the data has 'x' as the key in the data. My data has the label 'date_time' as the key. I have tried to specify the the name of the key using the xAxisKey parameter in the parsing options but this results in a blank chart.

This is my code:

```js
var xyValues = [{
    date_time: '2022-11-13 23:00:00',
    value: 2.3
  },
  {
    date_time: '2022-11-14 00:00:00',
    value: 3.1
  },
  {
    date_time: '2022-11-14 01:00:00',
    value: 4.5
  },
  {
    date_time: '2022-11-14 02:00:00',
    value: 5.1
  },
  {
    date_time: '2022-11-14 09:00:00',
    value: 5.5
  }
]

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: xyValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: 'date_time',
      yAxis: 'value'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

How should the parsing be coded so that key from the data is correctly parsed as the x values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature of Chart.js V3 and onwards so you need to update the Charts.js library to a newer version.

And that should be `yAxisKey: 'value'` instead of `yAxis: 'value'`

```js
var xyValues = [{
    date_time: '2022-11-13 23:00:00',
    value: 2.3
  },
  {
    date_time: '2022-11-14 00:00:00',
    value: 3.1
  },
  {
    date_time: '2022-11-14 01:00:00',
    value: 4.5
  },
  {
    date_time: '2022-11-14 02:00:00',
    value: 5.1
  },
  {
    date_time: '2022-11-14 09:00:00',
    value: 5.5
  }
]

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: xyValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: 'date_time',
      yAxisKey: 'value'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using V2 of the lib while this feature got added in v3, so you either need to update your chartjs version or map your array to an object with an x and y key